# Data Wrangling in R: How to create a new column or row to use in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-wrangling

I created a separate tab in Excel to simplify original data because I had hard time data wrangling in R:

```
# Country Code   Source         2013 2014 2015
# CAN            Hydroelectric  0.2  0.22 0.25
# CAN            Nuclear        0.3  0.34 0.35
# CAN            Oil, Gas, Coal 0.5  0.4  0.4
# USA            Hydroelectric  ..   ..   ..
# USA            Nuclear        ..   ..   ..
# USA            Oil, Gas, Coal ..   ..   ..
```

I want to create a stacked barchart and want to get Year as x and Electricity Production (% of total) from above for:

````
```
ggplot(electricity, aes(fill=Source, y=`Electricity Production (% of total)`, x=Year)) + 
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```
````

Comment: You will likely need to "pivot" the table from a "wide" format (years in columns) to a long format (year is a column), since that's the preferred data structure for `ggplot2`. For that, I recommend one of `tidyr::pivot_longer`, `data.table::melt`, or `reshape2::melt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = `2013`:`2015`) %>%
  group_by(CountryCode, name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
  mutate(value = prop.table(value) * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=Source, y=value, x=name)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~CountryCode, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CountryCode = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "USA", "USA", 
"USA"), Source = c("Hydroelectric", "Nuclear", "Oil,Gas,Coal", 
"Hydroelectric", "Nuclear", "Oil,Gas,Coal"), `2013` = c(0.2, 
0.3, 0.5, 1.2, 0.6, 1.9), `2014` = c(0.22, 0.34, 0.4, 1.2, 0.9, 
2.5), `2015` = c(0.25, 0.35, 0.4, 1.5, 1.2, 2.3)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```